# ReactJS application does not show any changes in /javascript/components

Tags: reactjs, ruby

I have the problem that on my server no changes to for example /app/javascript/components/Trials.jsx are shown after restarting the web-server. The server is currently running in dev mode and config.cache_classes = false is already entered in development.rb. Even if the server on which the ReactJS application is restarted, the changes are not applied. Does anyone know this problem and has a solution?

I have already changed everything possible in development.rb. Cache of the browser was also cleared to exclude the source here. Already spent a few hours on the internet to find a solution :D